# Adding 'download' attribute to <a> dynamically using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add the download attribute to an  tag dynamically. Here is what I have so far:

```
$(fclass).append('<a href="/files/'+$days[$i][2][1]+'" download>'+$days[$i][2][0]+'</a>');
```

Which produces this:

```
<a href="/files/day0.pdf" download="">Slideshow (Notes)</a>
```

I also added the exact same tag as this produces into my HTML manually, but instead of

```
<a href="/files/day0.pdf" download="">
```

I used

```
<a href="/files/day0.pdf" download>
```

The manual version works perfectly, and automatically downloads the file, however, the dynamically placed version does not.
I have also tried this:

```
$(a).attr("download","/files/day0.pdf");
```

But this does not seem to work. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you very much.

Comment: You left the quotes out of `$(a)`

Comment: @j08691 a is variable of a dynamically created <a> tag, not a single a element.

Comment: @PranavCBalan Still just links to the file, seems very odd. Not sure why, no download though.

Comment: ``$(a).attr("download","/files/day0.pdf");`` assigns the url to ``download`` attribute. Aren't you trying to assign the url to ``href``?

Comment: @YSJ The download attribute is meant to just download the file without redirecting to a separate page. So, in doing so, you must reference the files within the download attribute. I also tried using href, and just setting download to a attribute with no parameters, however this does not work.

Comment: The value assigned to download attribute is the name you want to save the file as. The url in href is the source you download from. I think you mean ``<a href="/files/day0.pdf" download>`` works. But some javascript you run didn't work. What's the javascript you run?

Answer (score 12):

The answer is

```js
$("a").attr("download", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="file-to-download.txt">Download the file</a>
```

Just checked an it is working :D

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using Props ?

```js
$(a).prop("download","/files/day0.pdf");
```

Comment: `download` is an attribute, not a property.